# undefined index for cookie in some browsers

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, cross-browser, browser

I am using a log in script that I found on experts exchange to make a cookie when a user logs on.

The login page processes like this:

```
function process_login() {

    var username = $.trim($('#input_username').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#input_password').val());

    username = $.trim(username);
    password = $.trim(password);
    var remember = document.getElementById("remember_user_checkbox").checked;

    if (!username || !password) {

        return false;

    }

    remember == true ? remember = "true" : remember = "false";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "login_user.php",
        data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&remember=" + remember,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data == "FALSE") {

                $('#input_password').val("");

                alert("The username or password you have entered is incorrect.");

                return false;
            }

            window.location = "orders-home.php?<?=time()?>";

        }

    });

}
```

And submits to `login-user.php`, here:

```
<?php
include('login-config.php');
$username = pg_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = pg_escape_string($_POST['password']);

//no encryption for now


//php gets this as a string
$remember = $_POST['remember'];

if ( $remember == "true" )
{
    $remember = TRUE;   
}
else
{
    $remember = FALSE;  
}


$user_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";

$user_result = pg_query( $con , $user_query );

if ( !$user_result )
{
    echo json_encode("FALSE");  
}


$arr = array();

if (!$user_result)
{
die( pg_last_error($con) );
}
else
{ 

       while ( $row = pg_fetch_array($user_result) )
       {

          //put the customer id in a session so we can put it in a cookie later
          //then when the page is refreshed the stored customer id will be used
          //as their ksisoldby identifier
          if ( $row['cust_id'] )
          {
             $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $row['cust_id'];
             $_SESSION['customer_name'] = $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];
             $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];


             if ( $remember )
             {
                remember_user($row["id"]);
             }
          }

         $arr[] = array(

         "first_name"          =>$row['first_name'],
         "last_name"           =>$row['last_name'],
         "customer_id"         =>$row['cust_id'],
         "accepted_terms"      =>$row['accepted_terms'],
         );   
       }

}

if ( empty($arr) ){
echo json_encode('FALSE');
}
else
{

    $path = '/webtrack';
    $site = 'www.isco.net';


    if ($remember === TRUE)
    {
         $remember_time =  time()+60*60*24*30;

         setcookie('username', $username, $remember_time, $path, $site);
         setcookie('customer_id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], $remember_time, $path, $site);
         setcookie('customer_name', $_SESSION['customer_name'], $remember_time, $path, $site);
        // setcookie('uuk', $uuk, $remember_time, $path, $site);

    }
    else
    {
         setcookie('username', $username, false, $path, $site);
         setcookie('customer_id', $_SESSION['customer_id'], false, $path, $site);
         setcookie('customer_name', $_SESSION['customer_name'], false, $path, $site);

    }

echo json_encode($arr);

}
?>
```

I then print from that cookie onto the main screen

```
<div class="fl customer_id">
    <?= strtoupper($_COOKIE['customer_name']); ?>
</div>
```

But I getting the error

`Notice: Undefined index: customer_name in /home/iscotest/public_html/webtrack/orders-home.php`

The actual site is www.isco.net. But the website is hosted at iscotest.com. isco.net simply points to iscotest.com. Could this be why my cookie isn't being set?

It is quite a problem because this totally ceases the load of the page, as that cookie information is used to retrieve the data that is displayed

The other odd thing is that this error isn't appearing consistently. I get the error on safari and chrome on one computer, but the site functions normally on another computer in safari and chrome.

Thanks for any help

Comment: SQL injection off the starboard bow, captain!

Comment: Is this the reason for the problem I'm having, or just, like, I'm not escaping things yet?

Comment: No, it's just a potential problem (and that's why it was just a comment and not an answer :-)  I'm not sure why the cookie isn't working.

Comment: The other cookies are working fine?

Comment: Yes, cookies are bound to domains. And yes, you're not escaping. (If you want to keep the cumbersome dated mysql_* interface instead of having that done implicitly with PDO and its simpler prepared statements is your silly choice.)

Comment: @Adnan I mean, it's not a link, but I put the site in the question. I'll fix it

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I also haven't encrypted passwords yet either :P I've changed the domain to `''` and it seems to work. Is that like, whatever top level domain the user's browser thinks it's at...or something. Is it like setting it to `'.'` ..?? Thanks!

Comment: @mario No, I reckon I'll switch to the prepared statements soon enough. I've only just learned about them though. I'm in the market for a good introductory resource if you have one in mind, though I admit my investigation is early days

Answer (score 1):

When you use setcookie () to create a COOKIE this will only be available on another page. Therefore, it can be a problem with your AJAX.

Comment: yeah, but it's redirecting to `orders-home.php` before it's asking for the cookie.. Maybe I misunderstood what you mean.