# undefined index $_COOKIE

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have a shopping cart which I store in a cookie. The cookie 'shopping_cart' is set once an item is added onto the cart.

```
function shopping_cart_add(){

      if(isset($_COOKIE['shopping_cart'])){
          $cookie_data = $_COOKIE['shopping_cart'];
          $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
      }else{
          $cart_data = array();
      }
         $data = array(
        "cart_id" => 1,
        "product_id" => $this->input->post('product_id'),
        "product_name" => $this->input->post('product_name'),
        "product_price" => $this->input->post('product_price'),
        "quantity" => $this->input->post('quantity'),
        "options" => $this->input->post('options'),
        "description" => $this->input->post('description'),
        "image" => $this->input->post('image')
        );
         $cart_data[] = $data;

      $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
      setcookie('shopping_cart',$item_data,time() + (86400 * 30));
      $_COOKIE['shopping_cart'] = $item_data;
    }
```

I am having a problem with when the user wants to remove an item from cart. I am using codeigniter framework but not its inbuilt cookies.

The following is the code in my view for deleting an item:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('designs/delete/');?><?=$values['product_id'];?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Delete</a></td>
```

The following is the code in my controller for deleting an item:

```
function delete($delete_id){
        $cookie_data = $_COOKIE['shopping_cart'];
        $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
        foreach ($cart_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($cart_data[$key]['product_id'] == $delete_id) {
                unset($cart_data[$key]);
                $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
                setcookie('shopping_cart',$item_data,time() + (86400 * 30));
                header("location:/category/cart_summary.php?remove=1");
            }
        }
    }
```

However I keep getting an error when I click the delete button.

```
Undefined variable $_COOKIE['shopping_cart']
```

Yet when I check my browser it show the cookie exists. What could be the problem?? I have already checked similar questions on stack pertaining to this issue but none has helped.
This includes:
[undefined index for cookie in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506833/undefined-index-for-cookie-in-some-browsers)
[PHP Undefined Index When Checking Cookie Value And Cookie Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376407/php-undefined-index-when-checking-cookie-value-and-cookie-exists)

Comment: Can you dump the value of  `$_COOKIE` ? it is empty ?

Comment: Yes when I dump the value of  `$_COOKIE` it is empty @KubiRoazhon

Comment: When you wrote `if(isset($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']))` maybe you mean `if(!isset($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']))`. Because the condition is not true and this way we never access to the code to fill the $_COOKIE variable.

Comment: No it is exactly as it should be because `if(isset($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']))` an item will be added to the already existing items

Comment: in your add function can you also dump the value and see if it is correctly adding/creating the cookie? also, as a side note, it is good practice to always check if variables *not* from db/hardcoded are set/not empty.

Comment: Yes the add function correctly adds item to cookie @Alex

Comment: there is no explanation (that I can think of) other than it getting deleted somewhere in between (but you said you can see it in the browser?). if it is set in add and you can verify it is, and if it is empty in delete at the first line before anything then something is happening in between. what i do not know and is out of the scope of the current code.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you didn't explicitly mentions on what path the `shopping_cart` cookies will be saved. Try to add a 4th parameter (path) at each `setcookie` :

```
setcookie('shopping_cart',$item_data,time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```